# Recovering files downloaded from IE

Tags: internet-explorer

A friend of mine has opened a Microsoft Publisher document from an e-mail (in gmail) in IE. They made changes to the file, repeatedly saved the changes, then closed Publisher. I've tried looking in Temporary Internet Files, but no joy.

Where else might the file be? Is there anything I can do to get the file back? They're running Windows Vista Home Premium.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening Word & looking into the list of recently opened files.
Also try to search the folder pointed out by the System Environment Variables: tmp & temp.

If Vista & Elevation on, it might happen that the file is created in a virtualization folder located at: `C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I found my file:

- go to Start menu
- click on Computer
- click on OS C
- click on Organize
- click on Folders and Search Options
- click on View
- click to enable *Show hidden files and folders*
- click to disable *Hide extententions for known files*
- click to disable *Hide protected operating system files*

When the box pops up and asks you if you really want to do this, click *yes*.
Click *Apply* and *Apply to folder*. Find the file under *publisher* or whatever you saved it under. I saw mine by the date and then I saw the actual name I assigned it.

After you save the file by clicking *Save As…*, go back and follow the above steps and enable the things you disabled and disable the thing you enabled, or click *Default Settings*. I did both.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Office Recent folder as well, there might be a shortcut in there pointing to the file:

%USERPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Office\Recent

Comment: Apologies, added clarification that it's Windows Vista.

Answer (score 0):

It should be somewhere in "C:\Documents and Settings\%%USER%%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5" (on windows xp).

On some other windows version you can always try opening another word document the same way through IE, then select "Save As" from the File menu and look where it is going to save that doc.

Comment: Apologies, added clarification that it's Windows Vista.

Comment: Well, that doesn't change the second part - open that doc through IE again (or some other document, it doesn't matter), pick "Save As" and look where it is going to save that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Publisher and see if it a list of resent files at the bottom in the File menu.

You also have a "Resent items" in the Windows Start menu where you might find a shortcut to it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to fix an issue like this is Vista not too long ago. IE stores files that it opens in a special 'low' directory for Protected Mode (yeah Protected Mode). To find the location of the actual temporary internet files go to:
"C:\Users\youruseraccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low"

Probably the most trival way to find publisher files though is to drill down the directory listing via the command-line. Open up a command prompt to the user directory and type in:

> dir /S *.pub

The should search all subdirectories for publisher file extension files. The file is likely going to be under that 'Low' directory.